# Python: return uma list em formato 2D

Tags: python, lista, método, return

Quero usar o `__str__` para receber uma `list` e retorna-la em forma de uma matriz.

Exemplo:

`list_exemplo = [[0,1], [2,3]]`retornaria como:

```
[[0, 1],
[2, 3]]
```

Como faço isso no método `__str__`?

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor? Você está implementando alguma classe para poder utilizar a `__str__`?

Answer (score 2):

como o Anderson ja apontou nos comentarios, vc deve implementar a função `__str__`, porem oq da a intender na sua duvia é que vc quer um feedback na hora da criação da lista, isso vc ja deve implementar o construtor `__init__`

```
class Lista(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        print(self.__str__())

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__().replace('],', ']\n')

a = Lista([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

esse exemplo ñ é final, acredito que ha formas melhores de se fazer isso

Answer (score 2):

Se você só quer formatar uma lista de listas na forma de matriz, não precisa criar uma classe pra isso - e aí não precisa de um método `__str__` - uma função que receba a sua estrutura de dados é o suficiente.

Agora, implementar uma classe tem outras vantagens: ela permite de fato tratar sua estrutura como uma matriz, e até implementar operações como são definidas para matrizes. Mas não vamos colocar o carro na frente dos bois.

PAra a formatação de impressão, um método fundamental de se entender é o  `.join` das strings - ele permite que strings que sejam parte de uma lista sejam coladas numa única string, usando a parte que chama o `.join` como elemento de cola entre elas. 
Nesse caso, o elemento de "cola" desejado é uma mudança de linha - para isso usamo so caracter especial `\n` (line feed). Se quiser apresentar os colchetes iniciais e uma vírgula no final de cada linha, de forma que a saída seja Python válido, pode fazer:

```py
def formata_matriz(matriz):
    return "[{}]".format(",\n".join(str(linha) for linha in matriz))
```

(Lembre-se que tem que usar um print(...) no resultado dela para que o \n seja expandido para uma mudança de linha:

```
In [617]: print(formata_matriz([[1,2],[3, 4]]))                                                                                                      
[[1, 2],
[3, 4]]
```

Se quiser algo mais com cara de "matriz" pode deixar de lado os colchetes de fora, as vírgulas no final, usar caracteres de formatação e tabulação da formatação, e o caracter `|` para delimitar a matriz:

```py
def formata_matriz(matriz):
    return "\n".join("|{}|".format(", ".join(
        f"{elemento:>5.2f}" for elemento in linha)) for linha in matriz)
```

Nesse caso uso uma f-string, eu faço uso da mini-linguagem de formatação do `.format` depois do `:` para garantir alinhamento a direita para os números, com espaço para 5 dígitos, sendo dois depois do . decimal:

```
In [630]: print(formata_matriz([[1.45,2.3],[23, 4.0]]))                                                           
| 1.45,  2.30|
|23.00,  4.00|
```